# SQL execution 2 seconds with LIMIT parameter, without only 0.2s why?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

This is my query and I need to return only 12 rows, but it takes 2 seconds with parameter `LIMIT 12` while it takes only <0.2 to process all ~600 results (without `LIMIT 12` or with `LIMIT 1200` for example).

```
Server version: 5.5.38-0+wheezy1 (Debian)
```

My question is, how could I improve this and why is this behaving this way?

```
SELECT uploaded.*, floor((upvotes * 100) / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS percentage_liked
FROM video_views 
JOIN uploaded ON video_views.file_name = uploaded.file_name 
WHERE conversion_finished != 0 AND active = 1 
GROUP BY file_name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 12 <--------- PROBLEM
```

Explain LIMIT 12

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys            | key           | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uploaded    | range | idx_file_name,idx_active | idx_active    | 4       | NULL                     |  545 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | video_views | ref   | idx_file_name            | idx_file_name | 14      | mydb.uploaded.file_name |  160 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Explain LIMIT 1200 (Why does it use now type index instead of range?)

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys            | key           | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | uploaded    | index | idx_file_name,idx_active | idx_file_name | 14      | NULL                     |  600 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | video_views | ref   | idx_file_name            | idx_file_name | 14      | mydb.uploaded.file_name |  160 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

tbl uploaded

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| file_name                | varchar(4)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| file_ext                 | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file_title               | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| file_description         | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file_tags                | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| upload_datetime          | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file_size                | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| file_name_keyword        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active                   | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| publish_after_conversion | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| thumbnails_created       | int(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| original_width           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| original_height          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| conversion_started       | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| conversion_finished      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quality                  | int(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| converted_width          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| converted_height         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| video_duration           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thumb_id                 | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| views                    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| upvotes                  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| downvotes                | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

tbl view_views

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_name | varchar(4)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ip_addr   | varchar(40) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| datetime  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you try the `EXPLAIN` with "LIMIT 12", but without "DESC" please. i.e. `ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 12`

Comment: It's almost the same as with `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 12`. Only in key `idx_file_name` is 67 rows instead of 160. But still it takes 2 seconds.

Comment: If you have a solution it would be valuable to have this documented as an answer.  It's OK to answer your own question and mark it as the accepted solution.  Can you do this, please?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGreen. You should submit your rewritten query an an answer. I am sure it will be upvoted.

Comment: Sorry, haven't been a while on Stack and totally forgot how to close the topic :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote query to the following, reduced query time to 0.016s:

```
SELECT *, floor((upvotes * 100) / (upvotes + downvotes)) AS percentage_liked
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS views, file_name 
   FROM video_views 
   GROUP BY file_name 
   ORDER BY views DESC 
   LIMIT 12
 ) p JOIN uploaded ON p.file_name = uploaded.file_name WHERE conversion_finished != 0 AND active = 1
```